# Android emulator: Auth0 login not working

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, android-emulator, auth0

For a school project we are using auth0 for the authentication of our app, but the login keeps failing for me (for the rest of my group it works if they use the same code as me). We are using a google account to login as an admin but it seems he is getting stuck after I click login (see screenshot). I also don't get any error message.

[image: Screen it gets stuck on when I try to log in]

I've tried reinstalling android studio, reinstalled multiple new emulators, recloning the project and so on. The information on the Internet didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the rest of your group can run this and it works, this means usually a hardware or software problem on your part. I had same issue, turns out it was software problem on android studio, missing dependencies or other plugins that interferes.

I would say try on another device in case this is hardware problem.